# plastic cutting sheets. how to use properly

Tags: cutting-boards

I bought some plastic cutting sheets in a pack of two. One side is smooth, the other side has a rough texture. Which side of the sheet should I cut on?

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more?  Show an example of what you're calling a cutting sheet, and what the 'rough' versus 'smooth' side is?  Depending on exactly what you mean, I could see the answer being either way.

Comment: ... and how does this relate to cooking?

Comment: @FuzzyChef : because it's an alternative to a wooden cutting board.  (or plastic one)  See https://www.amazon.com/Flexible-Plastic-Cutting-EZ-Grip-Waffle/dp/B014HPPAFS

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/84166/67

Comment: Ah, I think of "plastic cutting sheets" at the kind of thing you use for fabrics and paper crafts.

Answer (score 3):

The rough surface faces downward to prevent the board from slipping on smooth surfaces.

Comment: That's the way that I typically use them, as well.  If it's still too slippery, you can put a damp towel under the mat.  (and they also sell ones that are silicone on one side to grip the counter better)

Comment: Wouldn't the rough surface slip more on a smooth bench, since it has less contact area with the bench? Anecdotally, I find this to be the case for me.

Answer (score 2):

Are they very thin, hard but flexible sheets? Mine came with no particular instructions on which side to use, in fact all it said was that they were reversible - use either side or both.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I was wondering the same. I just visited a company's website and they described the "bottom" of their silicone cutting sheet as being textured (waffled) so as to provide a non-slip surface.

I might add that a smooth surface (cutting side) provides less of an environment for bacteria. (However, plastic is definitely not the best cutting surface as slicing itself creates a developing place for bacteria). A little bleach in the dish water is always wise. All in all, the convenience and flexibility for pouring makes these sheets popular and I use them daily.

Hope this helps.